# static_cast and RTTI vs dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, static-cast

Please observe the below code. As far as i know, dynamic_cast is slower than static_cast. Because it evaluates the type at runtime. 
My doubt here is    if we use static_cast with typeid() as below , will it takes same time as dynamic cast ?? 
Will it be faster than dynamic_cast ?

```
class Shape
{ 
public:
  virtual ~Shape(){}
};
class Circle : public Shape{ };
class Square : public Shape{ };
```

Static cast with RTTI:

```
Circle c;
Shape* s = &c; // Upcast: normal and OK

// More explicit but unnecessary:
s = static_cast<Shape*>(&c);
// (Since upcasting is such a safe and common
// operation, the cast becomes cluttering)

Circle* cp = 0;
Square* sp = 0;

// Static Navigation of class hierarchies
// requires extra type information:
if(typeid(s) == typeid(cp)) // C++ RTTI
    cp = static_cast<Circle*>(s);
if(typeid(s) == typeid(sp))
    sp = static_cast<Square*>(s);
if(cp != 0)
    cout << "It's a circle!" << endl;
if(sp != 0)
    cout << "It's a square!" << endl;
```

Dynamic cast:

```
Circle c;
Shape* s = &c; // Upcast: normal and OK

s = &c;
Circle* cp = 0;
Square* sp = 0;
cp = dynamic_cast<Circle*>(s);
    if(cp != 0)
    cout << "It's a circle!" << endl;
sp = dynamic_cast<Square*>(s);
if(sp != 0)
    cout << "It's a square!" << endl;
```

Comment: This will only work if you _dereference_ the pointers to the objects. Only then will `typeid` work with the dynamic type of objects, instead of just giving you `Circle*` and `Shape*` back.

Comment: Hi Pileborg,Thanks for your suggestion, I just want to know time diff between them. I will check with any predefined functions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is faster to test the type and then do the `static_cast`, but the operations are not equivalent as that will only allow downcast to the most derived type (any intermediate level will not be matched with the `typeid`). I would use `dynamic_cast` as it is more robust (will not break if someone extends your type and passes a pointer, for example).

If performance of `dynamic_cast` is an issue in your application, you should reconsider the design. While `typeid` + `static_cast` is faster than `dynamic_cast`, not having to switch on the runtime type of the object is faster than any of them.

Answer (score 3):

Those code samples are not logically the same. You forgot that `dynamic_cast` takes class inheritance into the account, and comparing typeid() compares only the **leaf** part of the inheritance tree. The only thing the typeid gives you is the "some unique identifier related to the actual type of that object". With typeid() alone you cannot check whether a cast to a pointer of a common base is possible, you can check only if the runtimetype-of-that is exactly the same as runtimetype-of-otherthing.

Saying that, I think that static_cast+typeid should be a somwhat faster in the general sense, but will simply give wrong answers in some cases.

Comment: typeid gives you an unique identifier related to actual type of the object at runtime only, doesn't it ?
typeid() alone is not sufficient ?? I think it does the runtime check as dynamic_cast does. Am i wrong please correct me

Comment: Yes, it works only at runtime. At the time of compilation it is unknown and none of your comparisons can be optimized away.

Comment: @ranganath111: The point is that if you have a hierarchy of `A`, `B` and `C`, with `typeid` you can only test whether the object is of the most derived type `C`, but not whether it is a `B`. If your code does not care whether the actual type is `C` or `C'`, but just that it is in the `B` branch of the hierarchy, that can be done with `dynamic_cast` but not `typeid`. Also note that it is usually a bad idea to switch on types, and more so with `typeid`. If some time in the future someone extends the hierarchy with `D` that will not be matched in any of the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine any decent compiler would be able to optimize both examples to the same code. However, the only way to find out is to measure the results for your specific toolchain.

Comment: Actually compilers cannot optimise something like this that depends on information at runtime (perhaps they could with _this specific example, but introduce anything the compiler can't know or predict, and it would go out the window). The `typeid` comparison does a single comparison between two pointers, while `dynamic_cast` walks the inheritance tree, so theoretically the former should be faster. But yes, you should measure the results.

Comment: @SethCarnegie I certainly did not mean to imply that the compiler would optimize out RTTI, though I agree that it's possible in a very simple case. Rather, I believe that it could infer that this usage of `typeid` and `static_cast` together is a simply a user-implementation of `dynamic_cast` and such it would output the same code in either case.

Comment: Well, `static_cast` and `typeid` used this way is most definitely not a `dynamic_cast`. As I said before, they do completely different things: one compares two types directly, the other compares many types. Also `dynamic_cast` has different behaviour on failure as well, so the compiler would be in error to change the `static_cast` version to `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: @SethCarnegie - just what I wrote, consider expanding my post? I can turn it into wiki if you think it's not clear

Comment: @SethCarnegie I see your point, my answer focuses on the exact code given and does not consider the possibility of additional classes in the inheritance tree. I assume that in the case that no additional classes exist as link time, I would be correct, but in general, I am incorrect. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Only one way to be sure. Measure it with std::chrono and [high_resolution_clock](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/chrono/high_resolution_clock/).

Comment: I will check and let you know. Thanks alot